# Batch File in efforts to compare numbers

Tags: math, batch-file, comparison, batch-processing, negative-number

I've been trying to make a batch file that can deal with negative numbers for a while now. My best guess was to create the small "engineer" in the batch file that would add 1000 to each number during the comparison, and revert the numbers to normal after comparison. 
My computer runs Windows 8, and when I run this batch file, it comes out saying that Beta (which should equal -93) is greater than ALL the numbers even after the "engineer" does its work. I'm not sure how to fix this. Help?

```
 @echo off
 :PRELOAD
 set alpha=0
 set beta=0
 set gamma=92
 :MONKEYWRENCH
 set /a beta=%beta% - 93
 echo Monkey Wrench
 :ENGINEERSTART
 set /a alpha=%alpha% + 1000
 set /a beta=%beta% + 1000
 set /a gamma=%gamma% + 1000
 :ECHOMONKEY1
 echo Alpha = %alpha%
 echo Beta = %beta%
 echo Gamma = %gamma%
 :COMPARE
 echo Start Comparison
 echo Alpha
 if '%alpha%' GEQ '%beta%' echo Alpha is greater than Beta
 if '%alpha%' LSS '%beta%' echo Alpha is lesser than Beta
 if '%alpha%' GEQ '%gamma%' echo Alpha is greater than Gamma
 if '%alpha%' LSS '%gamma%' echo Alpha is lesser than Gamma
 echo Beta
 if '%beta%' GEQ '%alpha%' echo Beta is greater than Alpha
 if '%beta%' LSS '%alpha%' echo Beta is lesser than Alpha
 if '%beta%' GEQ '%gamma%' echo Beta is greater than Gamma
 if '%beta%' LSS '%gamma%' echo Beta is lesser than Gamma
 echo Gamma
 if '%gamma%' GEQ '%alpha%' echo Gamma is greater than Alpha
 if '%gamma%' LSS '%alpha%' echo Gamma is lesser than Alpha
 if '%gamma%' GEQ '%beta%' echo Gamma is greater than Beta
 if '%gamma%' LSS '%beta%' echo Gamma is lesser than Beta
 echo End Comparison
 :ENGINEEREND
 set /a alpha=%alpha% - 1000
 set /a beta=%beta% - 1000
 set /a gamma=%gamma% - 1000
 :ECHOMONKEY2
 echo Alpha = %alpha%
 echo Beta = %beta%
 echo Gamma = %gamma%
 pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove all of the quotes.

`'%var%'` where var=-83 is the string `'-83'` - including the quotes. Batch then executes an **ALPHABETICAL** comparison, chracter-by-character, so `'123'` is less than `'9'` because `1` is less than `9`

Comment: If both sides of the comparison operator are resolved to a valid signed 32-bit number, then the comparison will be performed on the MAGNITUDES, otherwise the STRINGS on either side are compared. AFAIAA, STRING-comparison will take place left-to-right on the ASCII value, where `-` has a higher value than `+` but lower than any numeric, hence any negative will 'correctly' be determined as "less than" any UNSIGNED numeric but "greater than" a signed positive numeric. Where the signs are identical then a numeric comparison crossing into STRING territory will be compared on the leftmost different.

Comment: @foxidrive - IF does ***not*** collate by ASCII code when comparing non-numeric strings. Uppercase letters start at 65, and lowercase letters start at 97, yet `if a lss B (echo TRUE) else echo FALSE` returns TRUE. IF does sort alphabetically, with lowercase sorting before uppercase.

Comment: @dbenham I could be wrong then - that was my understanding.  There is a problem with your explanation too as `if z lss B (echo TRUE) else echo FALSE` returns FALSE.  Maybe it uses the craptacular `findstr` logic ;)

Comment: @foxidrive - I meant that it sorts first alphabetically, and in the event of a tie, lowercase sorts before upper: a < A < b < B  etc. I believe there are non-English letters with diacriticals mixed in as well.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks Dave. Is there a documented explanation for the compare rules? Google didn't return anything easily.

Comment: @foxidrive - I haven't seen any. I've only done experiments, but not enough to fully explore the collation rules. I believe I found that it differs from FINDSTR, and I know that it differs from SORT.